# MySQL Replication: Seconds Behind Master super high

Tags: mysql, replication

I've set up a slave db server for my production database, but when I checked the show slave status, I noticed a super big number in seconds behind master.

This is the output:

```
           Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
              Master_Host: 1.2.3.4
              Master_User: replicator
              Master_Port: 3306
            Connect_Retry: 60
          Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000173
      Read_Master_Log_Pos: 15909435
           Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000079
            Relay_Log_Pos: 91173356
    Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000093
         Slave_IO_Running: Yes
        Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
          Replicate_Do_DB: 
      Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
       Replicate_Do_Table: 
   Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
               Last_Errno: 0
               Last_Error: 
             Skip_Counter: 0
      Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 91173210
          Relay_Log_Space: 8179978166
          Until_Condition: None
           Until_Log_File: 
            Until_Log_Pos: 0
       Master_SSL_Allowed: No
       Master_SSL_CA_File: 
       Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
          Master_SSL_Cert: 
        Master_SSL_Cipher: 
           Master_SSL_Key: 
    Seconds_Behind_Master: 486330
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
            Last_IO_Errno: 0
            Last_IO_Error: 
           Last_SQL_Errno: 0
           Last_SQL_Error: 
Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
         Master_Server_Id: 1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR: 
No query specified
```

Then when I run SHOW PROCESSLIST, I see that the time of the thread matches the time indicated in seconds behind:

```
mysql> SHOW PROCESSLIST;

| 40 | system user |           | NULL | Connect |  66530 | Waiting for master to send event | NULL             |
| 41 | system user |           | NULL | Connect | 486330 | Reading event from the relay log | NULL             |
| 45 | root        | localhost | NULL | Query   |      0 | NULL                             | SHOW PROCESSLIST |
```

That time is dropping, slowly. Read_Master_Log_Pos,  Relay_Log_Pos, Exec_Master_Log_Pos and Relay_Log_Space are changing all the time.

I've also check the time/date and both servers are on sync.

On the Master side:

```
mysql> SHOW PROCESSLIST;

| 66739 | replicator | 1.2.3.5:52884 | NULL                | Binlog Dump |    65671 | Master has sent all binlog to slave; waiting for binlog to be updated | NULL
```

and show slave hosts looks empty...

```
mysql> SHOW SLAVE HOSTS;
+-----------+------+------+-----------+
| Server_id | Host | Port | Master_id |
+-----------+------+------+-----------+
|         2 |      | 3306 |         1 |
+-----------+------+------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

So what is actually going on here? Looks like the slave is actually connected and working, but very very slow? Can someone give me some hints on how to do more debug on this? Server is rather idle at 95%.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you see the `Seconds_Behind_Master` that high, I look at the following:

```
Relay_Log_Space: 8179978166
```

You have  7.6182GB of relay logs to process.

```
Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000173
Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000093
```

This tell me that you have read up to `mysql-bin.000173`, but you are currently processing things from the `mysql-bin.000093`.

This also tell me you have about 80 binary logs on the Master, each about 100 MB.

The `Seconds_Behind_Master` is simply the NOW() minus the TIMESTAMP set at `mysql-bin.000093` (Relay_Master_Log_File) position `91173210` (Exec_Master_Log_Pos).

As long as Slave_SQL_Thread is Yes, the relay logs get processed

- `Relay_Log_Space` will decrease each time a relay log is done
- `Exec_Master_Log_Pos` will increase until current relay log is done, then resets to the beginning of the next relay
- TIMESTAMP keeps increasing, which make `Seconds_Behind_Master` decrease (NOW() minus the TIMESTAMP set at Relay_Master_Log_File position Exec_Master_Log_Pos)

This is what happens when replication is off for 486330 seconds (5 days 15 hours 5 minutes 29 seconds) and you run `start slave;`

Look at your `SHOW PROCESSLIST;`. The IO Thread has been up for 66530 seconds (18 hours 28 minutes 50 seconds). This means someone or something started replication 18 hours 28 minutes 50 seconds ago.

You stated in your question that you have set up replication for the production server. This means that you ran the mysqldump 5 days 15 hours 5 minutes 29 seconds ago and started replicating from the production master 18 hours 28 minutes 50 seconds ago.

If you had setup the Slave the same day you got the mysqldump from the Master the replication load would be a lot less. Notwithstanding, replication is working normally provided `Slave_IO_Thread` and `Slave_SQL_Thread` both say `Yes`.

Comment: Correct. The SLAVE START was scheduled to run one day after the MASTER dump but it did not happen, so I had to SLAVE START after a long weekend. What I've done is setting innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2 and this has reduced the LAG. How safe is to do this?